# How to modify the name of this sheet in Python

Tags: python

I have around 200 lists like this:

`list1 = [element1, element 2, ...]`

`list2 = [2nd_elem1, 2nd_elem2, ...]`

In the end I've combined them all into one list

`master_list = list1+list2+list3+...`

My problem is, I then export this list to excel with

`df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = master_list[i])`

This names each sheet with the name of the element, but i'd like each sheet to be named list1_1, list1_2, list2_1, list_2 etc. Is there a simple way I can achieve this without having to go back and change 200 lists?

Comment: how do you make `df` ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = f'list_{i}')
```